# Warning: include(): Failed opening 'parth' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php70/lib/php') in /bluehost parth/index.php on line 3

Tags: php

I upload my site and database in to cPanel bluehost When me connection database by code below it show error:

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'parth' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php70/lib/php') in /bluehost parth/index.php on
line 3

so all developer help fix me for this error...

DB config

```
<?php

    /*
    * All database connection variables
    */

        $host="localhost";
        $username="root";
        $password="";
        $dbname="db_name";

        $connection=mysql_pconnect($host,$username,$password) or die("connection to the server fail".mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection) or die("could not open db:$dbname");

        function db_connect()
        {
            if(!$connection)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if(!mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return  $connection;
        }

        function login($user,$pass)
        {
            db_connect();           

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '".$user."' AND password = '".$pass."'");

            $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

            if($num_rows < 1)   return false;

            mysql_free_result($result);
            return true;
        }
            mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
            mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection ='utf8_general_ci'"); 
        ?>

include connection db 

        <?php
```

Include connection DB

```
<?php

    /*
    * I upload my site and database in to cPanel bluehost When me connection database by code below it show error:
    */
            //error_reporting(E_ERROR|E_PARSE);
            include 'atsschool/db_function.php';
            if(empty($_GET['p']))
            {
            $_GET['p']='home';
            }
            if(empty($_GET['page']))
            {
                $_GET['page']='1';
            }
            if(empty($_GET['l']))
            {
                $_GET['l']='english';
            }

        ?>
```

Comment: Warning: include(): Failed opening 'atsschool/db_function.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php70/lib/php') in /home1/hotelkci/public_html/atsschool/index.php on line 3

Comment: I guess the second file is index.php, in which case its in the same directory as the `db_function.php` file. You'll need to reference it as just `include 'db_function.php';` OR `include '../atsschool/db_function.php';`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
Replace the code in your connection script with code below and save it as config.php:

```
<?php
class DBController {
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user = "DBUSERNAME"; //Replace with your own db username
    private $password = "DBPASSWORD"; //Replace with your own db password
    private $database = "DBNAME"; //Replace with your own db name

    function __construct() {
        $conn = $this->connectDB();
        if(!empty($conn)) {
            $this->selectDB($conn);
        }
    }

    function connectDB() {
        $conn = mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password);
        return $conn;
    }

    function selectDB($conn) {
        mysql_select_db($this->database,$conn);
    }

    function runQuery($query) {
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $resultset[] = $row;
        }       
        if(!empty($resultset))
            return $resultset;
    }

    function numRows($query) {
        $result  = mysql_query($query);
        $rowcount = mysql_num_rows($result);
        return $rowcount;   
    }
}
?>
```

Then in your other scripts you're going to include the config.php like below:

```
<?php require_once("folder_where_config.php_is_located/config.php"); ?>
<?php
    if(empty($_GET['p'])) {
        $_GET['p']='home';
    }
    if(empty($_GET['page'])) {
        $_GET['page']='1';
    }
    if(empty($_GET['l'])) {
        $_GET['l']='english';
    }
?>
```

What I would then recommend is trying something like this for the login, of course you can modify this to your liking later and keep in mind you don't actually wanna use the code below because **mysql is deprecated**:

```
 <?php
    require_once("config.php");
    $db_handle = new DBController();


    if(!empty($_POST['username']) && ($_POST['password'])) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE Username=BINARY'".$_POST['username']."' AND password=BINARY'".$_POST['password']."'"); //You would use BINARY to make sure that the values match word for word, letter by letter, etc
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        $user_count = $row[0];
        if($user_count<1) {
            echo "error";
        } else {
        //place login function here
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Yes I See thanks you, I am  follow above code, but it still same before error .

Comment: but me use above code with database in goDaddy hosting is well, when me use this code with database in Bluehost hosting it's Error<<Warning: include(): Failed opening 'parth' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php70/lib/php') in /bluehost parth/index.php on line 3>>

Comment: so now how to do?

Comment: @SIENGCHAMPA send me a private email jeanmakes3@gmail.com, I'll be able to help you out a little more with this. Once we come up with a solution we'll share it on here.

Comment: Are you using shared hosting or VPS with Bluehost?

Comment: I use Share hosting Prime in Bluehost and domain name www.ats-school.com is add on domain

Comment: Is it alright if I send you an email on this email:info@ats-school.com?

Comment: thank you all dear for guide me to solve above error, now it already process. !!.... :D